# Azure Pipelines Tasks - How to query available versions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a situation where for stability reasons, we are locking some Tasks in our azure pipelines to specific versions.

For example, we might lock `S3Upload@1.10.0` (from the AWS Task Toolkit) or `PublishTestResults@2.180.0` (built-in task). We don't want these specific versions changing on us without doing a manual test pass on this pipeline.

However, there's no easy way to *tell* that a new version should be tested. Is there a comprehensive list of the task versions available in your account, or a way to ask via an API what the available versions of a task is? Ideally I could make an API call like `_apis/tasks/S3Upload/versions` and see what versions of that task are available for me to use in a pipeline.

(An API, query, or feed of some kind would allow us to gather up the changed tasks and queue them for a periodic manual test pass.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can use [Azure DevOps rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the list of installed extensions (could be pipeline tasks).
You can find version in the response as shown below

```
"extensionId": "pr-multi-cherry-pick",
  "extensionName": "PR Multi-Cherry-Pick",
  "publisherId": "1ESLighthouseEng",
  "publisherName": "Microsoft DevLabs",
  "version": "1.0.0.64",
  "registrationId": "204772b3-5f43-40f4-9c1b-c15c798f1544",
```

Comment: Tried this out and the body (very large) does contain the latest installed version for every extension task, which is great!  I may accept this answer unless someone can provide a way to do the same for _built-in_ tasks.  (You can even find the source at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks, but it's hard to tell if the versions in the task.json are actually deployed or not.)